BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved Techtalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.IUnitTestRuntimeProvider('nunit') error SpecFlow
I am trying to run Nunit Specflow Tests using TestCentric GUI, I can load the test dll but when I run the test, I get the following error
OneTimeSetup:Bodi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.IUnitTestRuntimeProvider('nunit')
I am using .NET Framework 4.8 with the following nuget packages
SpecFlow 3.9.74
SpecFlow.NUnit 3.9.74
NUnit 4.1.0
NUnit3testAdapter 4.5.0
Please let me know if this is a configuration issue on the .NET project or if some package is missing.
I can run the tests successfully using Visual Studio Test Explorer.


Please [edit] your question to include the C# code used to initialize the tests. We need a [repro], otherwise we cannot help you.
